# How to build a docker image with RSA key as build argument using Github Actions

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile, rsa, github-actions

I am trying to build a docker image using github actions on ubuntu-latest.
The docker image needs to receive an RSA KEY by build arg.

Although building the image in my macos machine works without any problem, I am facing the following error when building in github actions.

The keys are being stored as ENV variables and the command I am using is the following:

> docker build --build-arg user_private_rsa=$USER_PRIVATE_RSA . -t auth-service

Using the above command builds the image successfully on mac, but when using this gihub action, I have no luck at all.

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
jobs:
  build-deploy:
    name: Build docker image
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  build-push-ecr:
    name: Build docker image and push to ecr
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:  
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: docker build --build-arg user_private_rsa=$USER_PRIVATE_RSA . -t auth-service
      - name: Build image
        env:
          USER_PRIVATE_RSA: ${{ secrets.USER_PRIVATE_RSA }}
```

> bad flag syntax: -----END
> See 'docker build --help'.

The error occurs because executing docker build in github actions, ends up being a multiline command.

**Has anyone faced a similar problem and can help me fix it?**
Thank you very much!

Comment: Remember that it's really easy to copy files out of a Docker image, and `docker inspect` or `docker history` can show anything that gets set as an environment variable or used in a command line.  You probably do not want to inject an RSA key into your build like this.

Comment: Hey, this is a nice one! Did not remember that. thanks!

Comment: I notice now that you have a spurious dash (-) before name. The YAML parser starts a new step and the Docker step never sees the environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone have a similar problem, I solved it by passing the rsa keys as a base64 string, given docker is expecting a one line command.

Answer (score 4):

You should quote the variable, i.e. `--build-arg user_private_rsa="$USER_PRIVATE_RSA"` otherwise docker is picking anything after the first whitespace as an option for itself.

Comment: Hi Guilio, by doing so it did not take the content of the variable but the literal string $USER_PRIVATE_RSA. :(